# Does installing PHP using the Microsoft IIS Web Platform Installer require a restart?

Tags: php, server, iis, microsoft, web-platform-installer

Does installing PHP using the Microsoft IIS  Web Platform Installer require a restart?

I don't want downtime. *But I don't want to manually install it either.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It doesn't look like it is required but is recommended](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/616/using-the-microsoft-web-platform-installer/).

> **Best Practices for Using Web PI**
>
> Follow these best practices to prevent
>   errors or installation issues when
>   using the Web PI.
>
> Close all programs and restart your
>   computer.
>
> The Web PI functions by running the
>   setup for the selected applications
>   one after the other, as in a chain.
>   These setup programs are run
>   “silently,” meaning they run without
>   displaying a user interface. In some
>   cases, setup programs will block an
>   installation if certain applications
>   are running. For this reason, all
>   applications should be closed or
>   stopped. A simple way to do this is to
>   restart your computer. If an
>   application is configured to start
>   when Windows starts, you will need to
>   close it manually.
>
> Sometimes the Web PI encounters a
>   problem due to a pending restart.
>   Certain operations require a restart
>   (for example, if system dynamic-link
>   libraries (DLLs) are replaced by a
>   system update or hotfix installation).
>   Setup programs can, and do, block the
>   installation when a restart is
>   pending.

Answer (score 2):

From the previous times I have used it, I don't recall being prompted for a restart (although I usually install manually).  The best way to verify this would be to setup a dev server and test it.  This should be standard procedure before doing anything in a production environment, especially if you are concerned with downtime.

Measure twice...cut once.